# Compiler Errors-NSMutableDictionary for MultiTouchEvents

Tags: ios, event-handling, linker-errors, multi-touch

I'm trying to use an NSMutableDictionary to store the X and Y values of 4 touches, as shown in Apple's Event Handling Guide (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html)

My code is:

```
- (void)cacheBeginPointForTouches:(NSSet *)touches {
if ([touches count] > 0) {
    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        CGPoint *point = (CGPoint *)CFMutableDictionaryGetValue(_TouchesDict, touch);
        if (point == NULL) {
            point = (CGPoint *)malloc(sizeof(CGPoint));
            CFDictionarySetValue(_TouchesDict, touch, point);
        }
        *point = [touch locationInView:_view.superview];
    }
}
}
```

However, I keep getting compiler errors such as this:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_CFMutableDictionaryGetValue", referenced from:
  -[ViewController cacheBeginPointForTouches:] in ViewController.o
  "_OBJC_IVAR_$_UIViewController._view", referenced from:
  -[ViewController cacheBeginPointForTouches:] in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Does anyone have any suggestions for what I may be doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you added CoreFoundation framework? And imported header of this framework

Comment: @Iducool, yes, CoreFoundation framework is added

Answer (score 1):

replace `CFMutableDictionaryGetValue` by `CFDictionaryGetValue`.
the `CFMutableDictionaryGetValue` function seems strange to me. I think it does not exist

Comment: Hi @Toploulou, that got ride of one of the errors (Thanks!), but I'm still getting: 

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_IVAR_$_UIViewController._view", referenced from:
      -[ViewController cacheBeginPointForTouches:] in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)